# HOW to Identify APP Traffic in Android

Tags: android, traffic

From the technical standpoint, is it possible to differentiate the traffic from apps (exclude browser) and traffic from browser? 
Great thanks!

Comment: It *may be* possible. See TrafficStats (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) along with this blog - http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html

Comment: Sorry for not saying clearly, I mean if I redirect all the traffic to a proxy, is there a method to differentiate the traffic from apps (exclude browser) and traffic from browser at the proxy?